# How to use Seq with Cat in Chisel?

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip

I am learning chisel and rocket-chip.
The rocket-chip has a code using Seq and Cat in [RVC.scala](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/rocket/RVC.scala#L102).

```scala
    val funct = Seq(0.U, 4.U, 6.U, 7.U, 0.U, 0.U, 2.U, 3.U)(Cat(x(12), x(6,5)))
```

But when I write my code as above, I got an Error.
chisel reports type mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala provides a very powerful feature called [Implicit Conversions](https://dzone.com/articles/implicit-conversions-scala). I'll leave it to the many explanations on StackOverflow and otherwise findable by Google to explain the details and motivation, but let me explain how they are used in Chisel and Rocket Chip.

`Ints` in Scala (like `3`) are equivalent to primitive Java `ints`. If you check the [API docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/Int.html), you won't find any function `def U`, yet in Chisel we are able to construct `UInt` literals as `3.U`. This is accomplished with an *implicit conversion* called [`fromIntToLiteral`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/SNAPSHOT/chisel3/package$$fromIntToLiteral.html) that essentially allows us to define `def U` as if it were defined on the Scala `Int` class itself. By virtue of `import chisel3._`, you are importing `fromIntToLiteral` and telling the Scala compiler that actually, `Int` *does* have a method called `U`!

Rocket Chip has some of its own implicit conversions that the authors thought would be useful. In this case, `freechips.rocketchip.util` contains [`SeqToAugmentedSeq`](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/54237b5602a273378e3b35307bb47eb1e58cb9fb/src/main/scala/util/package.scala#L20) that defines `def apply(idx: UInt): T`, the function being called here*. Essentially, the Scala compiler is seeing that there's no `apply` method expecting a `UInt` defined on `Seq`, so it notices that `SeqToAugmentedSeq` is imported into the scope and provides such a method. It makes the following transformation:

```scala
val funct = Seq(0.U, 4.U, 6.U, 7.U, 0.U, 0.U, 2.U, 3.U)(Cat(x(12), x(6,5)))
// The compiler turns this into:
val funct = (new SeqToAugmentedSeq(Seq(0.U, 4.U, 6.U, 7.U, 0.U, 0.U, 2.U, 3.U))).apply(Cat(x(12), x(6,5)))
```

I hope this helps!

*Parentheses on an object is calling the [`apply` method](https://madusudanan.com/blog/scala-tutorials-part-15-the-apply-method/). `myUInt(3)` is equivalent to `myUInt.apply(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

This line declare a constant Seq :

```
//idx:0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
Seq(0.U, 4.U, 6.U, 7.U, 0.U, 0.U, 2.U, 3.U)
```

Then return an item (UInt) given by the index `Cat(x(12), x(6,5))`.

`x` should be declared as and `UInt` before. If we declare as it :

```scala
val x = "b0001000011000001".U(16.W)
```

We will have `x(12) = 1.U` and `x(6, 5) = 3.U` (or "b11".U) then `Cat(x(12), x(6,5)) == "b111".U == 7.U`

The index returned is 7 and correspond to 3.U in initially declared sequence Seq().

Then the value of funct will be :

```scala
val funct = 3.U
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.When I try to use "Seq(0.U, 4.U, 6.U, 7.U, 0.U, 0.U, 2.U, 3.U)(Cat(x(12), x(6,5)))", I meet a Grammatical error that "found   : chisel3.UInt, required: Int". Obviously, Seq needs an Int, But Cat returns UInt, which mismatch.